# My program return sometime true, but not always Codewars question "Are they same"

Tags: c, algorithm

i a newbie i am stuck on this question from Codewars. The question is that;

> - "Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) (compSame(a, b) in Clojure) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order."*
>
>   a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
>       b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
>
>   comp(a, b) returns true because in b 121 is the square of 11, 14641 is the 
>       square of 121, 20736 the square of 144, 361 the square of 19, 25921 the 
>       square of 161, and so on.
>
>   If we change the first number to something else, comp may not return true 
>       anymore:
>
>   a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
>        b = [132, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
>
>   comp(a,b) returns false because in b 132 is not the square of any number of a.

I think an algorithm with check all array but i can't make it possible.It is C language. I am writing codes on Visual Studio and this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
int tempVal1;
int tempVal2;

bool comp(int *a, int *b, size_t sizeArray)
{
    if (sizeArray == 0 || sizeArray == 0)
        return false;

    for (int k = 0; k < sizeArray; k++)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++)
        {
            if (a[k] == sqrt(b[i]))
                tempVal1 = 1;
            else
                tempVal1 = 0;
            printf("%d", tempVal1);
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < sizeArray; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++)
        {
            if (b[k] == (a[i] * a[i]))
                tempVal2 = 1;
            else
                tempVal2 = 0;
            printf("%d", tempVal2);
        }
    }

    printf(" tempval1 : %d\n", tempVal1);
    printf(" tempval2 : %d\n", tempVal2);

    if (tempVal1 * tempVal2)
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main() {

    bool result;
    int a[8] = { 121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11 };
    int b[8] = { 121 * 121, 144 * 144, 19 * 19, 161 * 161, 19 * 19, 144 * 144, 362, 11 * 11 };
    result = comp(a, b, 8);
    printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: In `{ 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 362, 11*11 }` then 362 you have does not equal 19^2.

Comment: Is it C or C++?

Comment: Try sorting both arrays first, this will make your algorithm simpler

Comment: @Jabberwocky it is C Jabber

Comment: @Robindar thanks for answer. how can i do it?

Comment: @NathanOliver there is 362. so return should be false.

Comment: @fury All of your elements in `b` are the same element in `a` squared, right?  If so the 362 should be 361 as 19^2 is 361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's code is functionally wrong as the `tempVal1`, `tempVal2` only depend on the the final loops `a[k] == sqrt(b[i]))` and `(b[k] == (a[i] * a[i])` compares.

Instead the inner `for (i...)` loop needs to find a match.  When none is found, return `false`.

```
bool comp(const int *a, const int *b, size_t sizeArray) {
  for (size_t k = 0; k < sizeArray; k++) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++) {
      long long aa = (long long) a[i] * a[i];
      if (aa == b[k]) {
        break;
      }
    }
    // Since the loop did not exit early, no match was found, return fasle
    if (i == sizeArray) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for (size_t k = 0; k < sizeArray; k++) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++) {
      long long aa = (long long) a[k] * a[k];
      if (aa == b[i]) {
        break;
      }
    }
    // Since the loop did not exit early, no match was found, return fasle
    if (i == sizeArray) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

---

Using FP math for an integer problem leads to precision, range and round-off issues that are best avoided.

Consider a "square" test without those problems

```
bool is_aa_square_of_a(int aa, int a) {
  if (aa < 0) return false;
  if (a == 0) {
    return aa == 0;
  }
  int q = aa/a;
  int r = aa%a;
  return q == a && r == 0; 
}
```

---

Note: Code could be made more time efficient using sorted arrays.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your answer and spending your time. It works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be traversing each element in 'a' for each element in 'b' and check if  square of 'a' is available in 'b'.

Complexity would be `O(n^2)`.

```
    bool comp(int *a, int *b, size_t sizeArray)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < sizeArray; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++)
            {
                if(b[i]<0)
                  return false;
                if ((a[k]==0 && b[i]==0) || (a[k] ==(b[i]/a[k]) && (b[i]%a[k]==0)))
                    break;
                if(i+1==sizeArray)
                  return false;
            }
        }
       return true;
    }
```

Another solution would be to sort both the arrays-`O(nlogn)`

and check `if a[i]==b[i]/a[i] && b[i]%a[i]==0`  which will be `O(n)`.

So total Complexity would be `O(nlogn)`

Comment: @Kevin yeah it should be.changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Natarajan.

Comment: Nice improvement - now only the small corner `a[k] == -1, b[i] == INT_MIN` breaks code.

Comment: @chux how to handle that case. will it be efficient if I have the result in long and not as int. is there any way of improving it?

Comment: @NivedhithaNatarajan Note `int` and `long` may be the same range, so using `long` is not a certain solution.  Could use _some_ wider type like `long long` or `intmax_t`, yet even those are not certainly wider than `int` - jut more likely than `long`.  Highly portable code simply tests to insure `a[k] == -1 && b[i] == INT_MIN` is not true before `b[i]/a[i]` via some means.  Example: [`is_aa_square_of_a()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632380/2410359).